# How to get a SharePoint List Item By Unique Id

Tags: sharepoint-2010, get, uniqueidentifier, sharepoint-clientobject

Is it possible to get SP List Item by unique Id (without writing a Caml request) if I know a related List Id.

```
var item = list.GetItemById("CFA9E204-6509-424B-A246-0DE5295C42B2");
```

When I tried to get item using this code, I received an error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

What's wrong with the GetItemById() method?

Why does it has an overloaded method GetItemById() with a string argument if it understands only integer Id?

**EDIT**:

I use SharePoint Client Object Model where List entity has no a method GetItemByUniqueId(), but it has the GetItemById() method, which receives string or integer Id.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Any luck getting the item using a guid?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`SPListItem item = list.GetItemByUniqueId(new Guid("CFA9E204-6509-424B-A246-0DE5295C42B2"));`

Comment: Thanks, but this method is not presented in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. I have updated question and provided reference on MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible to load a listitem by it's unique identifier.you can use the SPList.GetItemByUniqueId method

see [MSDN documentation on GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but this method is not presented in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. I have updated question and provided reference on MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with following method, need your suggestions if its something looks workable

```
            CamlQuery cQuery = new CamlQuery();

            cQuery.ViewXml = string.Format(@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                                      <Query>
                                                        <Where>
                                                          <Eq>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='UniqueId' />
                                                            <Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value>
                                                          </Eq>
                                                        </Where>
                                                      </Query>
                                                    </View>", id);

            //ListItem item = listItem.GetItemById("293");

            ListItemCollection itemColl = listItem.GetItems(cQuery);

            sp.Context.Load(itemColl);

            sp.Context.ExecuteQuery();

            ListItem item = itemColl.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`spliste.Items[<uniqueId>]` should work.

For example:

```
Guid itemUniqueID = new Guid("bb49fd4e-c302-45ef-85dc-e12624423651");
SPListItem item = spliste.Items[itemUniqueID ];
```

If you want to get the content of a certain field of that item:

```
string content = spliste.Items[<uniqeId>][<fieldGuidOrDisplayName>].ToString();
```

For example:

```
Guid itemUniqueID = new Guid("bb49fd4e-c302-45ef-85dc-e12624423651");
string content = spliste.Items[itemUniqueID ]["Title"].ToString();
```